# For loop to copy cells from one sheet to another works but gives an error at the end of the loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, error-handling

I have wrote a simple For code which is actually working but after it gives me all the values i want, it goes on error "run-time-13 type not matching". I am copying the code in the hope that a more expoert eye might catch something. Thanks a lot if you give it a look.

```
Sub REPORT()

Dim ipt As String
Dim foc As Worksheet

Set foc = ActiveSheet

ipt = foc.Range("C2")

a = Worksheets("DB").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To a

If Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 5).Value = ipt And Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 24).Value = "Achieved" Then

B = Worksheets("field").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("field").Activate

Worksheets("field").Cells(B + 1, 2) = Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 4)


End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What are `Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 5).Value` and `Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 24).Value` equal to when the error occurs?

Comment: At what row, exactly the error appears?

Comment: `If Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 5).Value = ipt` this is the wrong line

Comment: Whatever that value is, it's something that can't be compared to a string.

Comment: Moving the cursor over the `Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 5).Value`, what does it show? Even better, put this line on top of the problematic one: `Debug.print Worksheets("DB").Cells(i, 5).Value`. What does it show in Immediate Window?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, sorry for late replay I got the notifications on my spam. I actually found out that I had an error in tha dataset (#N/D), so the loop stopped at that point. I know it's something basic but i am new to VBA. Thanks again for all the suggestions!